# Kafka DLQ configuration for json message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, dead-letter

I have a SCDF stream with two processors. The goal of the stream is to read the jsonb from the source topic and processed/parsed into the jdbc postgres. Mostly, the json is big enough to completely parsed and getting the error.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 4277122 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

Although increasing the max.request.size help solving the error, but my main task is to implement the functionality of DLQ.

I try to configure the Kafka DLQ to get the error message in the DLQ topic.
Following are the configurations I implemented:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqName=error.dlq
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.auto-commit-offset=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.auto-commit-on-error=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqProducerProperties.configuration.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqProducerProperties.configuration.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.deserializationExceptionHandler=sendToDlq
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=headers
```

After running the SCDF stream, the DLQ topic is creating into the kafka but still the Record too large exception message not moving to the DLQ topic.

Is there any configuration missing or entered wrong? I have gone through other similar questions but couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You said you are reading JSON from Kafka and writing to postgres - so how can you get a producer error? In any case, the exception information is added as headers to the DLQ record.

Comment: I have pushed the json through connector to Kafka topic, from topics processors are reading the json. This is how i am creating the stream: stream create --definition ":postgres.public.topic > processor1 | processor2 | jdbc

Comment: So the problem is in the output stage of processor1? Is it increasing the size of the JSON? In any case, as I said, the exception information will be in headers in the DLQ record.